# prove that if given $n$ islands and $n-1$ bridges, and no loops are formed, all the islands are connected

Tags: number-theory

prove that if given $n$ islands and $n-1$ bridges, and no loops are formed, all the islands are connected.

Ideally, I would like a non-graph theory solution, if it exists.

I can't really get anywhere on this....I don't even know if it is true (It is a small part of a problem I'm trying to solve)

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by a non-graph theory solution. You've just asked a graph theory **question**. (And what's what the `number-theory` tag?)

Comment: Try induction on $n$.

Comment: ehh....this is a part of a proof from a competition number theory problem (I don't know from where)..so maybe my proof was wrong.

Comment: @Eternal The answer below answers this question sufficiently, so maybe you should post the problem itself and attempted proof as a different question.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Mike's comment, here is a *graph theoretic* answer

Use induction:

Clearly true for $n=1$ and $n=2$

Suppose that it is true for $n$ islands and we have $n+1$ islands. At least one of the islands must have only one bride to it (if all have two or more, then the number of bridges has to be as many as the number of islands ...see below). Remove this island and the bridge to it. This process cannot break a loop. Remaining $n$ islands do not have a loop by induction hypothesis.
To prove the parenthetic comment, suppose $B_k$ is the number of  bridges that connect the island $k$. Let $B$ be the total number of bridges. If you add all the bridges over all the islands you count a bridge twice and hence
$$
\sum_k B_k = 2 B
$$
So if all $B_k \ge 2$ then $B$ is at least equal to the number of islands.

Also, since all the islands are connected $B_k \ge 1$. Hence, if the number of bridges are less than the number of islands then at least one $B_k$ is equal to 1.